# C# parsing number from string

Tags: c#, function, parsing, numbers

I need to turn a string like

> 0000000002000

into

> 20.00

The last two digits in the input string are after the decimal point.  Currently I'm using:

```
string szCena = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName).Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
string szVrednost = "";
bool bFound = false;

foreach (char brojka in szCena)
{
  if (bFound)
  {
    szVrednost = szVrednost + brojka;
  }
  else
  {
    if (brojka != '0')
    {
        bFound = true;
        szVrednost = szVrednost + brojka;
    }
    else
      continue;
  }
}

szVrednost = szVrednost.Insert(szVrednost.Length - 2, ".");
```

Comment: What is the rule to turn `0000000002000` into `20.00` and not `2.000`?

Comment: Int32.TryParse then divide by 100

Comment: @Eser well the last 2 should be decimals. It will be used for printing price on fiscal paper

Comment: Please fix your variable names, this is just gibberish for most people here; use English.

Comment: @Filkolev - I can appreciate your concern. Since we want OP's to copy and paste their code here with little or no editing, rather than to type their code in, converting identifiers to English would involve refactoring his source code or heavily editing posted code, either of which would be counterproductive.

Comment: @BobKaufman, my recommendation is to **write** code in English in the first place. As a former student of programming in a non-English speaking country, I was taught that using such variable names is bad practice. Later I started teaching the same thing. And although understanding everything in the program isn't always necessary here, having a context is usually helpful. I just can't let a bad piece of code slip by without a remark on how it can be improved, it's my nature I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making all those string concatenations with chars you could use the native framework methods that tries to convert an input string in a numeric value, perform some simple mathematical division and then reconvert your number to a string using the [numeric custom formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string input = "0000000002001";
decimal  value;
if (decimal.TryParse(input, out value))
{
    value = value / 100;
    string result = value.ToString("0.00");
    Console.WriteLine(result);

}
else
   Console.WriteLine("Input is not a valid number");
```

Notice that I have added a final 1 at your sample input to show decimal handling

Comment: Thank you so much! This was what i actually need :P